# inserting and get image from sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert an image into a table which has a column with type (image). Here is what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO tblDDPhotos(ID, img)
VALUES (1, SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET(BULK 'blob:http%3A//localhost%3A64527/81655427-3653-427d-92bf-254cd2a2e647', SINGLE_BLOB) as imagefile)`
```

I wanted to know,

1. How do we insert the image from blob.
2. How can we access and retrieve the image.
3. What are the disadvantage of storing an image in the DB as over to saving the image in a folder in the server.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix the `VALUES` and the `SELECT` approaches in your `INSERT` statement - use one **or** the other, but you cannot mix them.

So one way to do this would be to use:

```
DECLARE @FileContents VARBINARY(MAX)

SELECT @FileContents = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'blob:http%3A//localhost%3A64527/81655427-3653-427d-92bf-254cd2a2e647', SINGLE_BLOB) as imagefile)

INSERT INTO tblDDPhotos(ID, img)
VALUES (1, @FileContents)
```

or the alternative approach would be to use:

```
INSERT INTO tblDDPhotos(ID, img)
   SELECT 1, BulkColumn
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'blob:http%3A//localhost%3A64527/81655427-3653-427d-92bf-254cd2a2e647', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

Pick whichever approach suits you better - both work equally well.

Side note: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.

[See details about this here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. but this will not work if the image is in a different instance right? is there any way for it?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane: what do you mean by *different instance* ??